# how to solve derivative equation from python

Tags: python

I am new from sympy method and I want to calculate the derivative of binomial equation based on user's input.

```
from scipy.misc import derivative 
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol("x")

sign = input("What is the operator of the equation? ")
a = int(input("What is the value of a? "))
expo = int(input("What is the value of exponent for x? "))
b = int(input("What is the value of b? "))


if sign == '-':
    ans = sp.diff(a * x ** expo - b,x)
    print (ans)

elif sign == '+':
    ans = sp.diff(a * x ** expo + b,x)
    print (ans)

def f(x):
    if sign == '-':
        ans = sp.diff(a * x ** expo - b,x)
        return ans

    elif sign == '+':
        ans = sp.diff(a * x ** expo + b,x)
        return ans

print (derivative(f,2.0))
```

I am having an error from the function f(x). Using the function of this, it will show the derivative of the equation above. For example of the equation is (6x^2 - 2). The value of x = 3

f'(x) = 12x -> This should be shown as an answer

f(3) = 36 -> This should be shown as an answer to the function f(x)

Comment: your f function isn't returning anything

Comment: Edited it but still having an error (Can't calculate derivative wrt 1.00000000000000.)

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Can't calculate derivative wrt 1.00000000000000.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and clearly explain how to run the code, exactly what you expect to see, and exactly what you do see instead (copy and paste any error messages, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), and make sure they are [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol("x")

sign = input("What is the operator of the equation? ")
a = int(input("What is the value of a? "))
expo = int(input("What is the value of exponent for x? "))
b = int(input("What is the value of b? "))


if sign == '-':
    f = a * x ** expo - b

elif sign == '+':
    f = a * x ** expo + b

derivative = sp.diff(f,x) # derivative of the function

print (derivative) #prints the derivative as a function of x
print (derivative.subs(x,3)) # prints the derivative evaluated at x=3
```